# Question about liquid / gaseous insulators

Tags: resource-recommendations, insulators

I'm looking for information about liquid / gaseous insulators, but I can't find any, is there any website (because I can't find on Wikipedia) where I can get this information? Also, can I get a list of examples of liquid / gaseous insulators? Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All gases are insulators as long as they are not ionized since without ionization there are no free charged particles there that can carry electric current. Ionization can be caused by high temperature, or by strong electric field. Sufficiently high temperature or strong electric field (more on the latter in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_breakdown) will tear electrons away from atoms or molecules and convert any gas (actually any liquid or solid as well) into plasma which is a great conductor. But without converting into the plasma state, some liquids are good conductors because they contain free electric charge carriers, e.g., liquid metals contain freely moving electrons; or water with some salt dissolved in it contains positive and negative ions.